# Why this code snippet said to contain error?

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator, assignment-operator

I know normally, * and & signs. But our teacher gives us an example and she said "Problem occurs here"

```
int *a1;
int *a2 = new int[100];
a1=a2 //What does this line mean???
delete []a2;

k=a1[0]//she said error occurs here.
```

I couldn't understand what is a1 = a2 ?
and why does error occur?

Comment: `delete` is not C. Seems to be C++. Edit: @GürkanÇatak You should know the language (I guess) by attending a class/course.

Comment: It is not my own example or question. Her example.

Comment: `a1=a2` means `Copy the address stored in a2 to a1`. The `k=a1[0]` has a problem because the code does `delete [] a2`, effectively freeing the memory allocated and hold by pointers `a2` and `a1` (remember it's the same memory address), and after the deletion, it tries to dereference (access) it via `a1`, which will likely cause a crash. A pointer that points to a region of memory that was free'd is called a dangling pointer.

Comment: Don't you avoid compilation errors by putting `;` at the end of a statement?

Comment: "*I couldn't understand what is a1 = a2 ? and why does error occur?*" --> "*`//she said error occurs here.`*": "*`k=a1[0]`*", not there "*`a1=a2`*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `a1=a2 //What does this line mean???`

`=` is the [assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)). This actually assigns the value of the LHS operand to the RHS operand.

Here, this line means, assign the value of `a2` to `a1`, i.e, this assigns the `a2` pointer to `a1`. That is, `a1` and `a2` points to the same memory location.

Now, once you call `delete[]` with `a1`, it actually frees the memory. Then, accssing either `a1[i]` or `a2[i]` is same, accessing already free-d memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To help understand, consider the analogy of a glass of juice with two straws into it. Once you have drank the juice via either of the straw, you cannot get anymore juice via the other one.

Answer (score 4):

After the line `a1=a2`, both `a1` and `a2` point to the same memory location.

Then when you run `delete a2[]`, the memory pointed to by `a2` is freed.  And since `a1` and `a2` point to the same memory location, `a1` is  also invalid.

Then when you dereference `a1`, which points to freed memory, you invoke [undefine behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 4):

It makes `a1` to have the same value as `a2`. As `a2` is a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, so it´s `a1`. The problem arises when you free the memory associated to that array. `a1` still holds the address of the now defunct array, and most probably, all operations that involve dereferencing `a1`, such as `k=a1[0]` will cause an illegal memory access.

Comment: Even if was the original pointer that was freed, that would hold the address of the now defunct array. Putting the pointer into another variable is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).